# 30, debt free and looking to invest $500-$1,000 a month

Tags: united-states, investing, savings, investment-strategies

I'm 30, debt-free, make max contributions to my Roth IRA and 401(k) and have six months of living expenses in a high-yield online savings account. I live frugally and am gainfully employed.

At this stage, I'd like to take my saving to the next level by investing $500 to $1,000 a month. Ideally would avoid fees and research/active oversight. Would love to hear your thoughts on some secure, high return options!

As a side note, I'd like to buy a house and start a family within the next five years, but my partner and I are saving for that separately. This would be for my personal savings and maybe early retirement if possible. Thanks so much!

Comment: At your age and savings rate, if you pick a house wisely, early retirement should be well within your reach if you just keep up the good work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you are rocking it! Good job. Sounds like you've done your research. Popular options for your situation are index funds and target funds, precisely because they have low fees and you can invest and forget. S&P 500 funds are a classic example.

You can also research some other ETFs and funds and diverse a bit. You'll get some answers suggesting a blend of stocks and bonds. Since you are young and have lots of time to be more aggressive, I'd suggest skipping bonds for a decade or so and invest in equities exclusively. (It'll be interesting to see how others feel about this)

Since you are investing a modest amount every month, be aware of trading fees. A no load mutual fund might be a better choice than a comparable ETF where you pay a trade commission every time you buy.

Comment: Note that if you buy Vanguard ETFs through Vanguard's brokerage there are no trading fees, and no fees to transfer in or out. (You'll only pay fees if you buy individual stocks)

Answer (score 4):

Secure, high return, low oversight: You can't get all three. Risk and possible reward are directly linked to each other, with efford invested biasing the result.

Reasonably low risk, market rate of return, very low effort: a mix of low-fee index funds, distributed across categories to get that diversification.